# Adjacency matrix for undirected graph

Tags: graph, adjacency-matrix

An adjacency matrix works well for a directed graph but not as well for an undirected graph because there are duplications in the matrix.

That is, during every insert to the graph, I have to update the matrix twice. Is there a way I can update the matrix only once? That is, is there a more efficient adjacency matrix for undirected graphs.

Comment: One alternative is to store only the edges `{i, j}` such that `i < j`, and then sort the nodes every time you access the adjacency matrix. But personally I'd rather duplicate each insertion than have an `if/else` on every access.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that and when I tried implementing it, it got super buggy.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a weight or cost, you can use weight/cost value instead of zero's and one's.

**example :-**

`1    2 
1 10   5
2 5    10`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid updating the matrix twice.

Comment: updating twice means assigning values, like {2,1} = 5 and {1,2} = 5 ?

Comment: Yes, that's redundant and annoying

Comment: even if the grap is an directed one then also you has to use {i,j} = value and {j,i} = value. The same has to be applied here right ?